# decrypting sql function

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the passcode to decrypt the function. I have read several articles about decrypting. I have logged in as DAC and tried to view it but unable. I used someone's SP from an article (SqlDecryptor) but it gives me an error 'Cannot perform alter on 'dbo.FunctionName because it is an incompatible object type'. I really need to look at the function. Does anyone have a way for me to decrypt and see the query text? Is there a way to use the passcode to decrypt? I am running SQL12.

I have never decrypted objects so forgive any ignorance please.

Comment: Have you looked at [The Internals of WITH ENCRYPTION](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/05/sql-performance/the-internals-of-with-encryption) - blog post  from @paulwhite ?

Comment: I read it however it flew over my head like the flying nun! can you type out the basic tsql that I would need to use to see the text of the function?